# Fetching the data from webpage with .cms extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the table from the webpage

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/companyid-0,duration-U,filtertype-latest,marketcap-All,pageno-1,pid-24,sortby-announcementDateStr,sortorder-desc,year-0.cms")
file_object = open('divident.csv', 'a')
```

output table as seen in screenshot is,

[image]

How to get the table and their values?

Comment: I just went to the url you are talking about, i think this can be done through web scraping and some manual data sorting. You can try `beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using some webscraping using `beautifulsoup4`

First we need to install the package named `beautifulsoup4`. then we can add the following import statement:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then we need to get the page source

```py
page_source = driver.page_source
```

Then we need to create a soup object

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
```

Then we can start by scraping out the headers

```py
data_display = soup.find('div', id='dataDisplay')
headers = data_display.find('div', class_='headers')
header_names = [x.find('b').text for x in headers.find('ul').find_all('li')]
```

now that we have headers we can start scraping out data:

```py
data_container = data_display.find('div', class_='dataContainer')
rows = data_container.find_all('div', class_='dataList')

final_data = []

for row in rows:
    row_data = [x for x in row.find('ul').find_all('li')]
    row_data2 = {}
    for col_name, value in zip(header_names, row_data):
        if col_name == "Company Name":  # Special case for column company name because it contains urls instead of text
            row_data2[col_name] = value.find('a').text
        else:
            row_data2[col_name] = value.text
```

Now you have your data scraped and you can choose any of the below methods to save it in either json or csv:

JSON:

```py
import json

with open("output_file.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(final_data, file, indent=4)  # You can remove indent=4 if you want it less size but leaving it will output human readable json.
```

CSV:

```py
import csv
with open("output_file.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, field_names=header_names)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in final_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

and to put it all together with your code:

```py
import os
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/companyid-0,duration-U,filtertype-latest,marketcap-All,pageno-1,pid-24,sortby-announcementDateStr,sortorder-desc,year-0.cms")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

data_display = soup.find('div', id='dataDisplay')
headers = data_display.find('div', class_='headers')
header_names = [x.find('b').text for x in headers.find('ul').find_all('li')]

data_container = data_display.find('div', class_='dataContainer')
rows = data_container.find_all('div', class_='dataList')

final_data = []

for row in rows:
    row_data = [x for x in row.find('ul').find_all('li')]
    row_data2 = {}
    for col_name, value in zip(header_names, row_data):
        if col_name == "Company Name":  # Special case for column company name because it contains urls instead of text
            row_data2[col_name] = value.find('a').text
        else:
            row_data2[col_name] = value.text

with open('divident.csv', "a") as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, field_names=header_names)
    # writer.writeheader()  # Uncomment this line if you are creating new CSV File, according to the question you are appending to the file

    for row in final_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Now you can modify the above code to meet your needs.

Here is a sneek peek of what is inside the variable `final_data`:

```json
[
    {
        "Company Name": "Manappuram Finance",
        "DPS": "0.75",
        "Dividend %": "37",
        "Type": "Interim",
        "Announce": "26-05-2021",
        "Ex-Div": "04-06-2021"
    },
    {
        "Company Name": "Kanpur Plastip",
        "DPS": "1.00",
        "Dividend %": "10",
        "Type": "Special",
        "Announce": "24-05-2021",
        "Ex-Div": "02-06-2021"
    },
    {
        "Company Name": "City Union Bank",
        "DPS": "0.00",
        "Dividend %": "0",
        "Type": "Interim",
        "Announce": "21-05-2021",
        "Ex-Div": "04-06-2021"
    },
    {
        "Company Name": "SBI",
        "DPS": "4.00",
        "Dividend %": "400",
        "Type": "Final",
        "Announce": "21-05-2021",
        "Ex-Div": "03-06-2021"
    },
    [...]
}
```

Comment: There was some error in writing to file. Solved that using csv.DictWriter(). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a decent amount of code that must be written to accomplish this. For an example, here's a quick way to scrape the values from the first two columns:

```
company_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.w160 > a')
dps_values = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.w90.alignR')
for i in range(25):
    print("Company Name: " company_names[i].get_attribute('innerText') + " DPS: " + dps_values[i + 1].get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Does that help to show how this could be accomplished with Selenium?

As you can imagine, keeping the data organized and getting output in the format you want is a challenge, especially for larger tables.